# Nested resource dictionaries

Tags: wpf, styling, resourcedictionary

I want to define multiple themes for my application and switch them every time I like, but I want to put styles of each control of each theme in a separate `ResourceDictionary`  so it makes files in a businesslike style and I can manage them fast and easily.
But the problem is:Styles of the nested Resource Dictionaries does not apply.
any suggestion?
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you were using seperate resource dictionary for each control and repeating it for your other themes as well. 
So I suggest you to keep a resource dictionary for each theme eg: Theme1.xaml .. and merge all your resource dictionaries which come under this theme.. 
example:

```
  <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UrProject;component/Themes/Theme1/Button.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UrProject;component/Themes/Theme1/Combobox.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UrProject;component/Themes/Theme1/ListBox.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UrProject;component/Themes/Theme1/Checkbox.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

You can add and remove this resource dictionary to your application for switching your theme. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: thanx ,Ive done the same, there is no exception , but the style doesn't apply.

Comment: the code is exactly like the xaml uve written, but the style does not aplly

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the theme to your application like this..

```
    public static void ApplyTheme(string themeName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(themeName) == false)
        {
            bool exist = false;
            string themeFileName =
                string.Format("/UrProject;component/Styles/{0}{1}", themeName, ".xaml");
            theme.Source = new Uri(themeFileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            foreach (ResourceDictionary dictionary in Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
            {
                if (string.Equals(dictionary.Source, themeFileName))
                {
                    exist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (exist == false)
            {
                Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(theme);
            }

        }
    }
```